# Besides $ω_{(1)}$ what space has Stone-Cech compactification and one-point compactification the same?

Tags: general-topology, compactification

For the ordinal space $ω_{(1)}$, the Stone-Cech compactification and the one-point compactification coincide. What is another such space?